# Graph API - /apprequests seems to return an empty JSON array every time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I use

```
https://graph.facebook.com/(userid goes here)/apprequests?access_token=(user access_token goes here)
```

it returns an empty JSON array like so:

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

Even though there ARE app requests.

These people were having the same problem, but didn't get their question answered either:
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=106693
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=88253

What am I doing wrong?

I tried POSTing and GETing requests with the Graph API Explorer, and THEY don't return an empty JSON array (however they only return the app requests POSTed by Graph API Explorer, not the requests for my app....I imagine this is to be expected however).  Could this have something to do with my app being in sandbox mode?  Does /apprequests work for anyone else's sandboxed app?

Comment: Are you trying to get the requests the user ***sent***?

Comment: no. the requests they _received_.  Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`apprequests`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) connection expect an [**app access token**](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#applogin).

Comment: it works! thanks!  It seems weird that they would need an app access token though.  I mean the user DOES have the power to delete app requests manually, so I don't know why the user's access token wouldn't be good enough.  Oh well.

Comment: Actually, using the user access_token did work a few weeks back. Now I got an empty data[] structure with the user access_token and an error with the app one...

Comment: I don't think this is an answer to the question. The question relates to getting all apprequests for a user. This answer suggests an app access token is required. Is that a token for an app which sent the request, or a token for the current app making the query? By definition, we don't know which app sent the request to this user until we see the requests.

I can't get any data with a querystring or with FQL. I'd really appreciate it if someone can post a more complete response that works with "today's" Facebook rules. Thanks!!

Comment: @TonyG, the OP wants to retrieve the user pending application requests, and calling the `appreqeusts` connection with an application access token will do the job. And what's with the multiple apps?! **YOUR** app can access the user's pending requests sent *from the **same** app*!

Comment: @ifaour, OK, it seems I'm trying to do something different as described in a [new question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7907168/get-apprequests-available-to-user-sent-by-other-users) that I just posted. Maybe Tkon-j can comment there too. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A few weeks back (around mid-september 2011), it was possible to get the requests with `https://graph.facebook.com/me/apprequests?access_token={user_access_token}`.

It does not seem possible today anymore. This call returns an empty data structure now.

Instead, calling `https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/apprequests?access_token={app_access_token}` does seem to work.

Comment: this is odd behavior.  I wonder why Facebook would start to restrict access to app requests in this way.  It sure would be useful to have Javascript get and delete apprequests, rather than leave it up to developer's servers.

Comment: They posted an annoucement a few days back telling that it was our duty to delete requests once accepted or ignored and no longer their. I guess the API change reflects that.

Comment: It does work just fine for me. Maybe it's something in the App Settings? (Facebook has been playing around these options for a while now)